# How to show bootstrap range's min max value before and after range slider?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using classical bootsrtap css to make a range. I'd like to show the min and max value as pointed in the picture above.

Just as a text explanation

> `[min value] [range bar/slider] [max value]`

as a straight line.

But my code shows three lines as

`[min value]`

`[range bar/slider]`

`[max value]`

Codes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap Range Input Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rangeInput">Range Input</label>
       22 <input type="range" value="30" id="rangeInput" oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value"> 222
       <output>30</output>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

[image: Bootstrap range min max value]

Edit:
Thank you for an answer. But I've added  to show current value. But can not make it work.

Comment: I've updated code to bootstrap 3.2.0 and I thnik it's about bootstrap version. But i can not update to 5.3.0 :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a flex box for it. Unfortunately I don't think Bootstrap 3.2 has in-built classes for that (please correct me if I am wrong), so you'd have to do with style tags, but works the same in the end.

Your code becomes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Bootstrap Range Input Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rangeInput">Range Input</label>
       <div style="display: flex; gap: 4px; align-items: center;">
       <span>22</span><input type="range" id="rangeInput"><span>222</span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all. At this time I can not update to bs5.

Comment: I've added oninput="this.nextElementSibling.value = this.value" parameter and after closing tag have an <outpt></output> before applyıng answer ıt was workıng. any help @siddharth-bhansali

Comment: It seems to work fine in the snippet. Though the min/max is 0-100. If you want those to be 22-222, you need to set that in the input itself. Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_range.asp